# Drupal website is broken on localhost

Tags: git, drupal, github, drupal-7, localhost

I have moved a drupal website from live server to localhost, its URL on localhost is something like this : localhost/webname/docroot/

But the problem I am facing is that everything is broken. no css, no images only text is visible on pages.

On my live website when I click on login button a popup for login appears. But on local host its not working. I have tried using different login URLs but non of them worked for me.

Site on localhost is very slow as well.

> Note :
>   Here is a URL of one image : localhost/sites/default/files/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-24%20at%206.08.54%20PM_0.png
>
> Similarly I have viewed source code of page and here are URLs of CSS and JavaScript files
>
> localhost/sites/default/files/css/css_UCtZrZRD9npGm4D7o8VXPkl5qDJq-m8IlhuR9ccf_tY.css
>
> localhost/sites/default/files/js/js_0gj6QcpfRH2jzTbCQqf7kEkm4MXY0UA_sRhwPc8jC1o.js
>
> These images and files are not found in this location, is this a cache problem ? All these files and images are missing from this location : localhost/sites/default/files

Comment: Do you have login form on /user page? Do you see img tags in page source. What files are their hrefs targeting? Do you have files there?

Comment: Here is a URL of one image : https://www.localhost/sites/default/files/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-24%20at%206.08.54%20PM_0.png

Similarly I have viewed source code of page and here are URLs of CSS and JavaScript files

https://www.localhost/sites/default/files/css/css_UCtZrZRD9npGm4D7o8VXPkl5qDJq-m8IlhuR9ccf_tY.css

https://www.localhost/sites/default/files/js/js_0gj6QcpfRH2jzTbCQqf7kEkm4MXY0UA_sRhwPc8jC1o.js

These images and files are not found in this location, is this a cache problem ? All these files and images are missing from this location : localhost/sites/default/files

Comment: I think this is a cache problem,.js files should not exist in sites/default/files... ordinarly, have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: As I am unable to login to admin so I tried clearing cache in phpmyadmin .. what else I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great migration guide on drupal's website : https://www.drupal.org/node/776864

Also, for the speed of your website, there are two things to keep in mind :

1. You local server might have different configurations and different hardwares
2. You have to disable `drupal_http_request_fails` in your settings.php `$conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE;` otherwise Drupal will try to connect to your localhost and the request will take some time to timeout which will slow your website.

Answer (score 0):

You've already mentioned your webroot is;

```
localhost/webname/docroot/
```

So it's unsurprising that your images don't resolve when they're attempting to be served from `localhost/sites/default/files` - they don't exist there, I assume they're in `localhost/webname/docroot/sites/default/files`?

You need to either set your vhost correctly, or edit your .htaccess file;

```
  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
```